# Can aeson handle JSON with imprecise types?

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I have to deal with JSON from a service that sometimes gives me `"123"` instead of `123` as the value of field. Of course this is ugly, but I cannot change the service. Is there an easy way to derive an instance of `FromJSON` that can handle this? The standard instances derived by means of `deriveJSON` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.4.1/docs/Data-Aeson-TH.html) cannot do that.

Comment: Have you considered writing aeson parsers instead of using deriving? You get full control that way. You can also write your own `deriveJSON` with your own `FromJSON` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to avoid writing `FromJSON` instances by hand as much as possible, perhaps you could define a newtype over `Int` with a hand-crafted `FromJSON` instance—just for handling that oddly parsed field:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text
import Data.Text.Read (decimal)

newtype SpecialInt = SpecialInt { getSpecialInt :: Int } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

instance FromJSON SpecialInt where
  parseJSON v =
    let fromInt = parseJSON @Int v
        fromStr = do
          str <- parseJSON @Text v
          case decimal str of
            Right (i, _) -> pure i
            Left errmsg -> fail errmsg
     in SpecialInt <$> (fromInt <|> fromStr)
```

You could then derive `FromJSON` for records which have a `SpecialInt` as a field.

Making the field a `SpecialInt` instead of an `Int` only for the sake of the `FromJSON` instance feels a bit intrusive though. "Needs to be parsed in an odd way" is a property of the external format, not of the domain.

---

In order to avoid this awkwardness and keep our domain types clean, we need a way to tell GHC: "hey, when deriving the `FromJSON` instance for my domain type, please treat this field as if it were a `SpecialInt`, but return an `Int` at the end". That is, we want to deal with `SpecialInt` only when deserializing. This can be done using the ["generic-data-surgery"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-data-surgery) library.

Consider this type

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import GHC.Generics

data User = User { name :: String, age :: Int } deriving (Show,Generic)
```

and imagine we want to parse "age" as if it were a `SpecialInt`. We can do it like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
import Generic.Data.Surgery (toOR', modifyRField, fromOR, Data)

instance FromJSON User where
  parseJSON v = do
    r <- genericParseJSON defaultOptions v
    -- r is a synthetic Data which we must tweak in the OR and convert to User
    let surgery = fromOR . modifyRField @"age" @1 getSpecialInt . toOR'
    pure (surgery r)
```

Putting it to work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    print $ eitherDecode' @User $ "{ \"name\" : \"John\", \"age\" : \"123\" }"
    print $ eitherDecode' @User $ "{ \"name\" : \"John\", \"age\" : 123 }"
```

One limitation is that "generic-data-surgery" works by tweaking `Generic` [representations](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#t:Rep), so this technique won't work with deserializers generated using [Template Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.4.1/docs/Data-Aeson-TH.html).

Comment: Apparently, these kinds of modifications can also be done with "generic-lens" http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-data-0.8.3.0/docs/Generic-Data-Microsurgery.html#g:1

Answer (score 3):

One low-hanging (although perhaps not so elegant) option is to define the property as an Aeson `Value`. Here's an example:

```
{-#LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
module Q65410397 where

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson

data JExample = JExample { jproperty :: Value } deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON JExample where

instance FromJSON JExample where
```

Aeson can decode a JSON value with a number:

```
*Q65410397> decode "{\"jproperty\":123}" :: Maybe JExample
Just (JExample {jproperty = Number 123.0})
```

It also works if the value is a string:

```
*Q65410397> decode "{\"jproperty\":\"123\"}" :: Maybe JExample
Just (JExample {jproperty = String "123"})
```

Granted, by defining the property as `Value` this means that at the Haskell side, it could also hold arrays and other objects, so you should at least have a path in your code that handles that. If you're *absolutely* sure that the third-party service will never give you, say, an array in that place, then the above isn't the most elegant solution.

On the other hand, if it gives you both `123` and `"123"`, there's already some evidence that maybe you shouldn't trust the contract to be well-typed...